# JSON Python MBTA API requests

Tags: python, json

I have been working on code for an MBTA API project, but I need some help. What code would I write to make the Python recognize that the JSON field I'm searching for doesn't exist?

Here is my code:

```
import urllib, json, time

localtime = time.localtime(time.time())

if localtime.tm_hour <=4:
realHour = localtime.tm_hour - 4 + 24
else:
realHour = localtime.tm_hour - 4

realMin = localtime.tm_min

#url = "https://api-v3.mbta.com/predictions? 
filter[route]=134&filter[stop]=9147&filter[stop_sequence]=3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,
36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50&include=trip,vehicle"
url = "https://api-v3.mbta.com/predictions? 
filter[stop]=Mishawum0&include=trip"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)

data = json.loads(response.read())
test = data['data']               
# THIS IS WHERE I HAD THE PROBLEM
#                                  V
if data['data'][0]['attributes'] != None:
    firstDeparture = data['data'][0]['attributes']['departure_time']
    firstId = data['data'][0]['relationships']['trip']['data']['id']

    search = 1
    didIt = False
    if firstId == data['included'][0]['id']:
        headsign = data['included'][0]['attributes']['headsign']
        didIt = True
    if didIt == False and firstId == data['included'][search]['id']:
        headsign = data['included'][search]['attributes']['headsign']
        didIt = True
    search+=1
    if didIt == False and firstId == data['included'][search]['id']:
        headsign = data['included'][search]['attributes']['headsign']
        didIt = True
    search+=1
    if didIt == False and firstId == data['included'][search]['id']:
        headsign = data['included'][search]['attributes']['headsign']
        didIt = True
    search+=1
    if didIt == False and firstId == data['included'][search]['id']:
        headsign = data['included'][search]['attributes']['headsign']
        didIt = True
    search+=1
    if didIt == False and firstId == data['included'][search]['id']:
        headsign = data['included'][search]['attributes']['headsign']
        didIt = True
    search+=1
    if didIt == False and firstId == data['included'][search]['id']:
        headsign = data['included'][search]['attributes']['headsign']
        didIt = True
    t = "T"
    print(headsign)
    firDept = firstDeparture[11:19]

    minute = firDept[3:5]
    hour = firDept[0:2]
    print(minute)
    print(hour)
    hour1 = int(hour) - realHour
    min1 = int(minute) - realMin
    if min1 < 0:
        if hour1 > 0:
            min1 += (60*hour1)
    arrMin = min1

    if arrMin > 0:
        print("NEXT TRAIN TO " + headsign.upper() + " IN " + str(arrMin) +   " MINS THIS IS A FLAG STOP PLEASE BE IN FULL SIGHT OF ENGINEER AS TRAIN APPROACHES")
    elif arrMin == 0:
        print("STAND BACK " + headsign.upper() + " TRAIN")
else:
    print("NO ARRIVALS AT THIS TIME. FOR SCHEDULING INFORMATION, PLEASE VISIT WWW.MBTA.COM")
```

Around the area where it says `if data['data'][0]['attributes'] != None:` is the problem. It keeps giving me errors instead of doing `else`. What am I doing wrong?

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mbta_headsign.py", line 18, in <module>
    if data['data'][0]['attributes'] :
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What sort of errors? Please update your question to include the *specific* error messages you're seeing, ideally with line numbers that correspond to your sample code.  If you print out `data['data'][0]` before that `if` statement, what does it look like?

Comment: @larsks I have updates it. That same error appears if i try to identify any json fields past "data"

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly identifies your problem.  The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "mbta_headsign.py", line 18, in <module>
    if data['data'][0]['attributes'] != None: 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The `IndexError` is telling you that you're trying to access a list item beyond the end of the list. In this case, you're trying to access `data['data'][0]`, and this error suggests that `data['data']` is in fact an empty list.

Instead of checking for:

```
if data['data'][0]['attributes'] != None:
```

Consider checking for:

```
if len(data['data']) > 0:
```

You can verify that this is the problem by following my suggestion in the comment and printing out the value of `data['data']` before your `if` statement.